# How to match ALL instances of a word and return each full row as array (as formula, not VB)

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that is updated with Job issues. Depending on the Issue the job is allocated to a various different team (each team in it's own tab).
Note. Each issue has a "Category" that has to be selected when filling out the job issue form.

I'm trying to write a formula that looks through the list of job issues and splits out different categories to different tabs (teams).

Here's the link to the Google Sheet to see what i've already done.

You can see my formula in E1 & L1 of "Team 1 tab"

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wKOMIM0JKf_jicYLeEy_Btu1atjpaGwyDlTMU2otlkc/edit?usp=sharing

See attached URL for code: You can see my formula in E1 & L1 of "Team 1 tab"

Lists all the matches in their own tab or area inside the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply with the `FILTER` function (although you can also use something like `QUERY`, it's not necessary for your application).

In your sheet, put this formula on the top-left of where you want data to begin:
`=FILTER('Form responses 1'!$A:$E,'Form responses 1'!$C:$C="Can't access a topic?")`

This should return all records in the range `'Form responses 1'!$A:$E` that match "Can't access a topic?".

You can see the documentation for the `FILTER` function here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en.

Comment: Fantastic, i've not used filter before but that's shortened it right down. It's also automatically arrayed it. Is this only a Google Sheets thing or is it also in excel?

Comment: It's also available in Excel if you have Office 365. Other than that, it's not available for use on other editions, and I'm unsure whether this functionality would be supported in standalone versions.

See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel-Blog/Preview-of-Dynamic-Arrays-in-Excel/ba-p/252944 for documentation on this.